# access denied when invoking "/authenticate" api with spring security

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I try to authenticate throught a /authenticate api to generate a token but it always gives me access denied even when username and password are correct.the problem was int the code of csrf().disabled().
I tried to remove CSRF().disabled() from the configure method it does remove the problem of access denied but it does not give me anything as a response, it does not generate the JWT(nothing is sent as a response).

Here is my controller:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api")
public class SecurityController {

@Autowired
private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

@Autowired
private MyUserDetailService userDetailsService;

@Autowired
private JwtUtil jwtUtil;

@GetMapping("/test")
private String test() {
    return "Test";
}

@GetMapping("/hello")
private String hello() {
    return "hello";
}

@PostMapping("/authenticate")
public ResponseEntity<?> createAuthenticationToken(@RequestBody AuthenticationRequest authenticationRequest)
        throws Exception {
    try {
        authenticationManager.authenticate(new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
                authenticationRequest.getUsername(), authenticationRequest.getPassword()));
    } catch (BadCredentialsException e) {
        throw new Exception("Incorrect username or password",e);
    }
    final UserDetails userDetails = userDetailsService.loadUserByUsername(authenticationRequest.getUsername());
    final String jwt = jwtUtil.generateToken(userDetails);
    return ResponseEntity.ok(new AuthenticationResponse(jwt));
}

}
```

securityConfig file:

```
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

@Autowired
private MyUserDetailService myUserDetailService;

@Autowired
public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth.userDetailsService(myUserDetailService);
}

@Bean
public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
    return NoOpPasswordEncoder.getInstance();
}

@Override
@Bean
public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
    return super.authenticationManagerBean();
}

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
    httpSecurity.csrf().disable().authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/authenticate").permitAll().anyRequest()
            .authenticated();
}

 }
```

[image]

Comment: Can you please post the error stack trace?

Comment: ok i have added the error

Comment: i have added the response from postman because i dont get any error in the backend

Comment: Have you tried disabling cors and csrf both like "httpSecurity.cors().and().csrf().disable()"

Comment: I have the same problem with this approach in my application. I don't have any idea why `/authenticatie` returns `401` status code.

Comment: the answer is to replace "/authenticate" with "/api/authenticate

Comment: thank you for your help guys :) i really appreciate it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your endpoints name is `/api/authenticate`.

so

```
.antMatchers("/authenticate")
```

wont work, you need to match on the correct url.